# how to turn on camera flash light or torch light using qt?

Tags: qt

I need to know how to turn on camera flash light or torch light using qt ? Is there any way to do this ? I am using qt 5.5. Please give suggestion.

Here is My code

```
#include "flashon.h"

FlashOn::FlashOn()
{
    cam = new QCamera;
    camExpos = cam->exposure ();
}

FlashOn::~FlashOn()
{
    delete this;
}

void FlashOn::lightOn()
{
    camExpos->setFlashMode (QCameraExposure::FlashOn);
    qDebug() << " light is on ";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please be more specific. Ex. Device, deployment, etc.

Comment: I am building an cross platform app to turn on camera flash light. My code is very simple, but it does not work.  What can I do ?

Comment: You can implement a objective c file into your C++ app (or something else), and then use the tibidabo solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882829/how-to-turn-the-iphone-camera-flash-on-off

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you read the documentation, there's `QCameraExposure::FlashTorch` in [`QCameraExposure::FlashModes`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcameraexposure.html#FlashMode-enum).

```
camExpos->setFlashMode(QCameraExposure::FlashTorch);
```

All devices may not support it:

> **QCameraExposure::FlashTorch** - `0x20` - Constant light source. If supported, torch can be enabled without loading the camera.

So you probably want to check to see if it is available:

```
if (!camExpos->isFlashModeSupported(QCameraExposure::FlashTorch)) {
    // ...not supported...
}
```

Comment: I have edited like this but no luck                                                                           cam->start ();
    if(camExpos->isFlashModeSupported (QCameraExposure::FlashTorch)){
        camExpos->setFlashMode (QCameraExposure::FlashTorch);
    }

Comment: @coder_hasib Well, if you edited it did you ensure that isFlashModeSupported returned true for the torch mode, such that the setFlashMode is being called?

Comment: I have checked but still no luck if(camExpos->isFlashModeSupported (QCameraExposure::FlashTorch)){
        qDebug() << "Flash supported";
        QMessageBox::information (this, "Info", "Flash supported", QMessageBox::Ok);
        camExpos->setFlashMode (QCameraExposure::FlashTorch);
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Flash not supported";
        QMessageBox::information (this, "Info", "Flash not supported", QMessageBox::Ok);
    } I got flash not supported, but i have a flash light on this android mobile. where is the problem ?

Comment: @coder_hasib If what you are trying to say is that you got "Flash supported" and it didn't work, then I would suggest you work from a complete example like the [Qt Camera Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html).  I didn't check before, but it seems there may be [more involved](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-camera-cpp.html) in setting up a valid camera instance than `new QCamera`, e.g. `new QCamera (QCameraInfo::defaultCamera())`.  So make sure you can run a working demo before trying this specific tweak.

Comment: I am sorry, I have read but can not find camera expose or anything related.